# How to install "gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf" specific version?

Tags: ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

Am performing cross compilation on x86 and target platform is armhf. When i run command
`apt-get install -y gcc-arm-linux* g++-arm-linux*`,  It installs **4.11.2.0** version and output is as below

```
g++-arm-linux-gnueabi is already the newest version (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1). 
g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf is already the newest version (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1).    
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi is already the newest version (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1).    
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf is already the newest version (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1)
```

But i need **4.9.3.0** version. How to install 4.9.3.0 version in ubuntu command line??

Am using ubuntu 20.04 and performing cross compilation using focal apt list

my /etc/apt.source.list file is as below

```
echo "### Copying ARM sources to /etc/apt/sources.list ###"
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe" >  /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main universe" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: download a pre-built from somewhere and untar it somewhere on your computer then set your path to point to it.

Comment: I need to install using command line and this command will be part of my cross compilation script. I don't want to build specific version by downloading and compiling.

Comment: @Karma Yogi This is exactly why old_timer is advising you to download/use a pre-built toolchain.

Comment: if you think ubuntu has every combination of gcc/binutils versions you desire, then go through their package history and select that package...otherwise find a pre-built and use wget and tar.

Comment: @Karma Yogi You may give a try with xenial instead of focal in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, since it would be a better match for gcc 4.9.3, having been released in 2016.

Comment: @Karma Yogi: Was the answer helpful in any way ? How could it be improved ? Thanks.

Comment: @Frant, I need to build on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal only, cant make it Xenial which is 16.04. Thanks for the suggestion by the way.

Comment: @Karma Yogi: Did you try downloading the pre-compiled toolchain ?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed-out by [old_timer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16007/old-timer), you could download/use a pre-built toolchain. You could  for example use the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` provided in [release 15.02](https://releases.linaro.org/archive/15.02/components/toolchain/binaries/arm-linux-gnueabihf/) of the Linaro toolchains - tested on Ubuntu 22.04:

Downloading/installing:

```
wget https://releases.linaro.org/archive/15.02/components/toolchain/binaries/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.02-3-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
tar Jxf gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.02-3-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
PATH=$(pwd)/gcc-linaro-4.9-2015.02-3-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin
```

Verifying gcc version:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Linaro GCC 4.9-2015.01-3) 4.9.3 20150113 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```